# Assigning a value to a variable in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a script that accepts an input date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

After that, I used sed to delete the hyphen (-) which gives me an output YYYY MM DD.

My question is, how can I assign those three numbers to a three different variable.

Example:

2013-11-23 will become 2013 11 23

```
echo "Please input date[yyyy-mm-dd]: "
read date
echo $date | sed 's/\-/ /g' #this will give me the output of yyyy mm dd
```

I want to assign that three numbers(yyyy, mm, dd) to a variable individually like this;

```
X=yyyy
Y=mm
Z=dd
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
X="2013 11 12"
read X Y Z <<<$(echo $X)
```

Comment: another question, how can I make sure that the variable for month and day will have a fixed digit of two. for example: Y=2 Z=9, I want those to become Y=02 and Z=09 and I want to be sure that when the input is double digit in won't return 3 digit. example Y=11 Z=23, it must not become Y=011 and Z=023

Comment: please ignore this, I got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
> now=2013-11-23
> year=`echo $now | awk -F- '{ print $1 }'`
> month=`echo $now | awk -F- '{ print $2}'`
> day=`echo $now | awk -F- '{ print $3 }'`
> echo $year.$month.$day
2013.11.23
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut command`

Here the resultant variable is seperated by space so cut command will split variable into seperate fields based on space delimiter `-d' '` and `-f1,2,3,...` will get the splitted field

```
result=`echo $date | sed 's/\-/ /g'`

X=`echo $result | cut -d' ' -f1`
Y=`echo $result | cut -d' ' -f2`
Z=`echo $result | cut -d' ' -f3`

echo $X $Y $Z
```

Answer (score 0):

If your need is just three variables with year, month and date in them. You can just do so simply by

```
#Get the year
X=`date '+%Y'`
echo $X

#Get the month
Y=`date '+%m'`  
echo $Y

#Get the date
Z=`date '+%d'`
echo $Z
```